# How to stop a child component from re-rendering a parent component in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a child component that is triggering it's parent component whenever it's clicked, which is not something that we want. I commented out all of the setState()s within the child component because I assumed that was all that would be triggering the re-render of the parent component but then I discovered AsyncStorage.setItem() is also triggering the parent to re-render. Does anyone know of a way in react native to stop the child from being able to trigger the parent to re-render?

Here is the code from the child component which is apparently bubbling up to the parent component and triggering it to re-render:

```
minusOne = () => {
    this.setState({
        total: this.state.total - 1
    });
    this.setState({ total: this.state.total - 1 }, () => {
        this.props.dispatch(handleQuantityCounterValue(this.props.data.productId, this.state.total));
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(this.props.data.productId.toString()).then((resultCount) => {

        if (resultCount !== null) {
            this.setState({
                total: parseInt(resultCount)
            });
        } else  {
            this.setState({
                total: 0
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code from the action:

```
export function handleQuantityCounterValue(productId, count) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
                type: types.HANDLE_QUANTITY_COUNTER
            }
        );

        AsyncStorage.setItem(productId.toString(), count.toString());
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, seems like it's happening because your parent component is subscribed to some piece of state that the `handleQuantityCounterValue` action updates. If possible, you can remove that piece of state from your parent components `mapStateToProps`.

You can also use [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to determine if the parent should re-render or not:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.field1 !== this.props.field1
}
```

Comment: How do you decide what property to compare on props?

Comment: @Tanya Well that will be up to you. You'll have to experiment and figure out which piece of redux state is forcing the parent to re-render. I don't know enough about your app to answer that for you.

Comment: Removing an unnecessary piece of state that was being returned in the reducer is what caused the parent component to no longer be re-rendered anymore.  Thx